# FB Javascript API not returning email despite using the scope variable

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having the hardest time trying to retrieve email via FB.login. Here is my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function(){
          FB.init({
            appId: 'appId',
                    cookie: true,
                    oauth: true
          });     

          $('#fbRegister').on('click', function(){
              FB.login(function(response){
                  if(response.authResponse)
                  {
                      FB.api('/me?fields=email,name', function(responseFromFB){                                                           

                          var name = responseFromFB.name; 
                          var email = responseFromFB.email;

                          //Take the vales and send to 
                          $.ajax({

                                type: "POST",
                                url: 'php/register.php',        
                                async: false,
                                data: {'name':name,'email': email},
                                success: function(data)
                                {
                                   $('#fbRegister').hide();
                                   $('#successPrompt').show().text(data);

                                },
                                complete: function() {},
                                error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                                {
                                  console.log('ajax loading error...');
                                  return false;
                                }
                         });

                      },{scope:'email,name'});
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      console.log('The login failed because they were already logged in');
                  }
              });                  
          });
        });
      });
```

In the App Center permissions I configured the User and Friends permission for email as well. Nothing seems to be working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the name field working?

Comment: Try removing the app from the test user's account (revoke permissions). Then log in again and see what happens. Permissions are not automatically updated after you add one in the array so that might be the problem.

Comment: Ok I went to my account and removed the app and logged in again to see if it works, no luck. When the dialog window pops up it doesn't even say this application is trying to use your email.

Comment: It just says this app is trying to access your public profile and friends list.

Comment: See my answer below, you misplaced the {scope: 'email, name'} object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing the scope parameters as an argument to the FB.api method. They need to be supplied to the FB.login method. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function(){
      FB.init({
        appId: 'appId',
                cookie: true,
                oauth: true
      });     

      $('#fbRegister').on('click', function(){
          FB.login(function(response){
              if(response.authResponse)
              {
                  FB.api('/me?fields=email,name', function(responseFromFB){                                                           

                      var name = responseFromFB.name; 
                      var email = responseFromFB.email;

                      //Take the vales and send to 
                      $.ajax({

                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'php/register.php',        
                            async: false,
                            data: {'name':name,'email': email},
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                               $('#fbRegister').hide();
                               $('#successPrompt').show().text(data);

                            },
                            complete: function() {},
                            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                            {
                              console.log('ajax loading error...');
                              return false;
                            }
                     });

                  });
              }
              else
              {
                  console.log('The login failed because they were already logged in');
              }
          }, {scope:'email,public_profile'});                  
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: That worked!!!! Thanks I really appreciate it. I don't know how I overlooked that.

Comment: That helped me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

pass `scope="public_profile,email"`  in button.

Answer (score 0):

answer above is almost perfect. Only thing won't work is scope:'email,name'
Should be scope:'email,public_profile'